# What does this equation represent?

Tags: electricity, mean-free-path

While doing the Franck-Hertz experiment I noticed that I have been asked to write the current as a function of the Mean Free Path as following: $$ I=a\cdot e^{-\frac{b}{\lambda}}$$
I- current

$\lambda$ - mean free path

a,b some constants that I try to figure out what they represent. So far, by simple dimension analysis, I understand $a$ should be current and $b$ should be length.
If anyone can tell me the name of that equation (if there is one) it will be much helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that it has a particular name in this context.  In the context of light moving through an absorbing medium, it's known as the [Beer-Lambert law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law);  but more broadly speaking, it's a general property of particles moving through a medium that can scatter them.  Similar equations exist for x-ray transmission and neutron transmission, and I'm not sure there's a specific name for those equations either.

Comment: If someone actually comes up with a common name for this equation, I'll delete this answer;  I just didn't want the question to go unanswered assuming that I'm correct.

Comment: I am not sure I understood what is $I_0$. this is not equation of time. so constant $b$ represent the distance of the lattice from the catode in that experiment?